# struts2 data cut in string send to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i've got this problem again...

So i've got String data in my Struts2 app. this data is quite big, 36KB data read from html with code:

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FILE.html"));
        String readData; 
        while( (readData = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileData.append(new String(readData.getBytes(),"UTF-8"));
        }
        reader.close();
        fileData.trimToSize();
        this.data2display = fileData.toString();
        this.setData2display(this.data2display.replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

I display data2display in my jsp file, with just:

```
<s:property value="data2display" escape="false" escapeJavaScript="false" />
```

Aaaaaand... This data is entire while i'm debugging controller, but while i try to display this in jsp. I've got only part of data. I haven't got any error/debug logs.

Any idea how to check it/fix it ?

My app: (struts2, jsp) everything is from **appfuse-basic-struts** archetype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal start point would be the source of PropertyTag, and from there on follow the code.

In this case, start with [PropertyTag](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/PropertyTag.java.html). You see that it extends [ComponentTagSupport](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/ComponentTagSupport.html), which in turn extends [StrutsBodyTagSupport](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/StrutsBodyTagSupport.java.html).

This is where it gets interesting; the `toString` method uses a [FastByteArrayOutputStream](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8-sources.jar!/org/apache/struts2/util/FastByteArrayOutputStream.java?format=ok) which uses a default block size (buffer) of 8192 bytes. Using the default constructor, as done by [StrutsBodyTagSupport](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/StrutsBodyTagSupport.java.html) you can't output a String with more data than that.

Being not an expert on Struts I hesitate to say that's an implementation bug; it should IMHO compute the buffer size from the `value` to be printed. Unfortunately, it doesn't. So I don't think there's an easy way around it.

The non-easy way is obviously defining a List of String data parts smaller than 8k bytes, and iterate over that list in the JSP, or just use c:out or something like that.

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I hope this will at least help you understand the trouble you're in.

Comment: @tzim the beauty of open source combined with Google :)